# comma seperated to square bracket expression node python function

Tags: python

As part of my automation project, I need a small python function to convert comma separated node expression to square bracket format node expression something like:

Input:

```
kvm10,kvm11,kvm12,kvm13
```

Output:

```
kvm1[0-3]
```

Comment: That's interesting.  Are you facing a problem?

Comment: Yes, certain keys are to be tested in such formats. Ive only been using the comma separated node. want a more effective function.

Comment: What does your function look like?

Comment: @IrthizaKhan What do you mean a "more effective" solution? Does your code work? Does it partially work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to recognize the name of the nodes, or you have a certain rule?

If the rule is the last digit, and everything is well behaved, you could use

```
node_list = split(expression,",")
node_name = node_list[0][:-1]
initial_node = node_list[0][-1]
final_node = node_list[-1][-1]
expression = node_name+"["+initial_node+":"+final_node+"]"
```

However if you must discover the name of the node, you probably should create a function that do just that as helper:

```
def find_name(one_node,two_node):
    i = 0
    name = ""
    while i<len(one_node) and i<len(two_node) and one_node[i]==two_node[i]:
        name += one_node[i]
        I += 1
    return name
```

Moreover, you can then use split again and find the position of the number in the node name using index+len(name)

The worst case will be if you have interruptions in your sequence, such as
m

node1,node3,node4

Then you probably must first get all numbers in a list, sort it and go one by one trying to make a sequence. When some number skips, you output one of your outputs.